# - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I found this method in a delegate file and inserted some code. The code never gets executed, even when the home button is pressed. When or how does this function get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `applicationDidEnterBackground` method if your app and OS support multitasking.

From `applicationWillTerminate` docs:

> For applications that support background
>   execution, this method is generally
>   not called when the user quits the
>   application because the application
>   simply moves to the background in that
>   case. However, this method may be
>   called in situations where the
>   application is running in the
>   background (not suspended) and the
>   system needs to terminate it for some
>   reason.

Comment: I thought the iPod touch doesn't multitask. Only one program runs at a time.

Comment: iPod touch 3G does - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#Features for what devices support multitasking (last row in the table)